# regarding a py4j exception

Tags: centos, py4j

I have installed Java 11 and Python 3 on CentOS. Trying to run a code that worked perfectly fine on a Windows environment. Getting this exception:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1188, in 
send_command
raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1014, in send_command
response = connection.send_command(command)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1193, in send_command
"Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "WordInformation.py", line 493, in 
status = read_from_source("../Corpora/Bhandarkar Oriental Research Books") 

File "WordInformation.py", line 473, in read_from_source
author, year)
File "WordInformation.py", line 381, in fetch_from_hwn
return read_store_properties(word, file, sentence, source, category, author, 
year);
File "WordInformation.py", line 79, in read_store_properties
properties["synsets"] = get_other_props(word)
File "WordInformation.py", line 226, in get_other_props
output = gateway.jvm.Properties.getProperties(word)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in 
call
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in 
get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling 
z:in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.examples.Properties.getProperties
```

Initialised the gateway as follows:
`gateway = JavaGateway.launch_gateway(classpath="/home/gayatri/Code/hindiwn.jar")`

Is this because of some dependency? I have set the JAVA_HOME and updated the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but

```
Answer from Java side is empty
```

But this error indicates that the Java code is not reachable. 
Just to verify basic steps

1) Be sure that the java program is running

2) Be sure that you run the Python script after the java code is running

3) The java program is running the entire time.

If you are doing those two things, then an issue may be that the operating system may be already using a port.

You can try

## Java

```
'GatewayServerBuilder server = new GatewayServerBuilder().javaPort(1001).build()'
'server.start()'
```

## Python

```
java = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=1001))
```